# Unable to load AWS Ivona Properties File Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using IVONA SpeachCloud SDK (Create speech sample): https://github.com/IvonaSoftware/ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/IvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech/SampleIvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech.java

Using this code for setting the class path

```
private static IvonaSpeechCloudClient speechCloud;

private static void init() {
    speechCloud = new IvonaSpeechCloudClient(
            new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("IvonaCredentials.properties"));
    speechCloud.setEndpoint("https://tts.eu-west-1.ivonacloud.com");
}
```

Below is the format for ivona.properties file. File is located in base directory. Required credentials i've got in my SpeechCloud account

```
accessKey = mykey 
secretKey = mysecretKey
```

Below is the exception I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from the /resources/ivona.properties file on the classpath
at com.amazonaws.auth.ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider.java:81)
at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.prepareRequest(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:279)
at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.prepareRequest(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:272)
at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.invoke(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:259)
at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.createSpeech(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:148)
at SampleIvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech.main(SampleIvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech.java:45
```

How can I solve this exception or how can I make a class to get around this and manually enter my accessKey and secretKey as a String.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this out after a few hours of messing around in the source files. You can make your own Provider Class where you can pass the credentials in as String Parameters.

**This is my custom credential Class "IvonaCredentials"**

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;

public class IvonaCredentials implements AWSCredentialsProvider{

public IvonaCredentials(String mSecretKey, String mAccessKey) {
    super();
    this.mSecretKey = mSecretKey;
    this.mAccessKey = mAccessKey;
}

private String mSecretKey;
private String mAccessKey;

@Override
public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials() {

        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mSecretKey;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mAccessKey;
        };
    };
    return awsCredentials;
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

**This is how I call my class**

```
private static void init() {
    speechCloud = new IvonaSpeechCloudClient(new IvonaCredentials("secretKey", "accessKey"));
    speechCloud.setEndpoint("https://tts.eu-west-1.ivonacloud.com");
}
```